# New Employee bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am new to bash scripting. I have a script that i am working on for a school project and its not working as expected. I keep receiving a error on my if then statements.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo –e “Would you like to add a new employee’s information? y/n \n”
read EMPLOYEE
if [ $EMPLOYEE = “y” –o $EMPLOYEE = “Y” ]
then
echo –e “Please enter employee’s first name  \c”
read FIRST
echo –e “Please enter employee’s last name  \c”
read LAST
echo –e “Please enter empolyee’s ID  \c”
read ID
echo –e “$FIRST\t$LAST\t$ID” >> database
fi
echo –e “Would you like to search for an employee? y/n \n”
read SEARCH
if [ $SEARCH = “y” –o $SEARCH = “Y” ]
then 
echo –e “Enter the first name, last name or employee ID to search for.  \c”
read WORD
grep “$WORD” database
fi
```

Comment: The quotes look wrong. It should be using ***`"`*** for the double quote, and not ***`“`***. There are some other odd characters in the script. I'm guessing the first thing you should do is use a different text editor.

Comment: What are your expectations? What is the error?

Comment: See http://shellcheck.net

Comment: I am using "y" as the quotes

Comment: At the moment the script errors out at line 4 stating that there are to many arguments

Comment: @DonMartin Use `[ "$EMPLOYEE" = "y" ] || [ "$EMPLOYEE" = "Y" ]`

Comment: Thank you andlrc this web site worked great to find my errors and will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 1):

With even a bash version 3 the following should work as you intended and be somehow shellitical correct ;-)

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Would you like to add a new employee’s information? y/n \n"
read -r EMPLOYEE
if [ "$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"$EMPLOYEE")" = "y" ]
then
    printf "Please enter employee’s first name : \c"
    read -r FIRST
    printf "Please enter employee’s last name : \c"
    read -r LAST
    printf "Please enter empolyee’s ID : \c"
    read -r ID
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s" "$FIRST" "$LAST" "$ID" >> database
fi
printf "Would you like to search for an employee? y/n \n"
read -r SEARCH
if [ "$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"$SEARCH")" = "y" ]
then 
    printf "Enter the first name, last name or employee ID to search for. : \c"
    read -r WORD
    grep "$WORD" database
fi
```

**Notes** on refactoring/repair:

1. Do not rely on `echo -e` in most cases printf works better and looks more like coding,
2. use `read -r`to mot mangle backslashes on input,
3. quote variables from input (with real ASCII quote characters), as the shell parser otherwise does funny things,
4. do not test against y and Y but simply lowercase the string received to only compare one variant.
5. Use some indent concept to track, and
6. use a shell linter as suggested by a commenter already (that one works nicely currently).

The above code does have no errors indicated in the above mentioned linter.

Small task for as exercise for the reader (thanks andlrc :)

7. Use lowercase variable names and I amend meaningful names 
   Enjoy the learning of the shell coding!

Comment: And please use lowercase variable names :-)